# Узнать текст тега html странички в python. BeautifulSoup

Tags: html, python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup

Есть тег sup, у него есть тег-родитель td. Как узнать текст тега td?
Вот код:

```
full_page = req.get(page_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(full_page.text, 'lxml')
full_info = soup.find("sup", id="cite_ref-JHU_ticker_4-0")
info = soup.full_info.parent()
count = soup.info.text()
print(count)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так

```
full_page = req.get(page_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(full_page.text, 'lxml')
full_info = soup.find("sup", id="cite_ref-JHU_ticker_4-0")
info = full_info.parent()
count = info.text()
print(count)
```